# Lines stroke (color) as legend and moving legend labels next to lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

I'm trying to use ggvis to make a plot similar to this one

[image]

and I'm running into two issues.

First, I've tried assigning the line stroke color as the legend shape but ggvis always keeps the circles. In addition, it doesn't recognize the dashed lines either.

```
library(ggvis)
  data <-data.frame(region=rep(c("A","B","C"),5),c=rep(seq(1980,2000,5),3), val=rnorm(15))

    data %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
    ggvis(~c, ~val) %>%
    layer_smooths(stroke=~region, strokeDash = ~region,strokeWidth := 3, strokeOpacity := 0.65) %>%
    add_axis("y", title="y") %>%
    add_axis("x", title="y", format=####) %>%
    add_legend(c("stroke","strokeDash")) ## Adding this does not update the legend to recognize the line color or dashes.
```

Some asked something [here](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/360) but no one answered.

Finally, I'd like to place the legend names of each region next to the lines just as in the first graph. For this, I haven't found out how to even start.

Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

I asked how to have x axis labels as numeric and the answer was adding format = "####" to add_axis.

Comment: This should probably be several separate questions, but here's a way to get the years without commas on the x axis: `add_axis("x", title="y", format = "####")`

Comment: Thanks! it worked seamlessly. As for the separate question, noted.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find what I needed specifically, but I found a partial solution. See the comments in the code.

```
data <-data.frame(region=rep(c("A","B","C"),5),c=rep(seq(1980,2000,5),3), val=rnorm(15))
data$region2 <- data$region ## create an additional region variable
data$region2 <- as.character(data$region2)
data$region2[data$c != 2000] <- "" ## Fill every year which is not the last year to be an empty character vector

data %>%
    group_by(region) %>%
    ggvis(~c, ~val) %>%
    layer_smooths(stroke=~region, strokeDash = ~region,strokeWidth := 3, strokeOpacity := 0.65) %>%
    layer_text(text := ~region2) %>% ## add this new region variable, which will only write over the last year.
    add_axis("y", title="y") %>%
    add_axis("x", title="y", format="####") %>%
    hide_legend(c("stroke","strokeDash"))
```